# DCC forecasting implementation in R (rmgarch) seems inaccurate?

Tags: r, correlation

I am trying to implement DCC (Dynamic Conditional Correlation) forecasting in R. However, when I try out some test values, the forecasting seems off compared to the Pearson correlation, especially when predicting correlations more than two years in the future. I am very new to R so I would really, really appreciate any help!

I am using the rmgarch package (found here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmgarch/index.html).

Here is my code:

```
library(quantmod)
library(rmgarch)
library(bizdays)
library(timeDate)

forecast <- function(ticker1, ticker2, start, end1, end2)
{
  startingYear = as.numeric(format(as.yearmon(end1), "%Y"))
  endingYear = as.numeric(format(as.yearmon(end2), "%Y"))
  hol = as.POSIXlt(holidayNYSE(startingYear))
  hol = as.character(hol)

  year = startingYear + 1
  while (year < endingYear)
  {
    temp = as.POSIXlt(holidayNYSE(year))
    temp = as.character(temp)
    hol = c(hol, temp)
    year = year + 1
  }

  #cal <- Calendar(holidays = hol, start.date = end1, end.date = end2, weekdays = c("saturday", "sunday"))
  #n.ahead = bizdays(end1, end2, cal)
  n.ahead = 252 * (endingYear - startingYear)

  dat1 = getSymbols(ticker1, src = 'yahoo', from = start, to = end1, auto.assign=F)
  dat2 = getSymbols(ticker2, src = 'yahoo', from = start, to = end1, auto.assign=F)
  dat1 = dat1[,4]
  dat2 = dat2[,4]
  eps <- data.frame(s1=dat1, s2=dat2)

  spec = ugarchspec()
  uspec = multispec(replicate(2, spec))
  spec = dccspec(uspec)
  fit = dccfit(spec, eps)
  result = dccforecast(fit, n.ahead)
  return(result)
}

con <- file("test.log")
sink(con, append = TRUE)
sink(con, append = TRUE, type = "message")
source("script.R", echo = TRUE, max.deparse.length = 10000)

startYear = 1998
endYear = 2014
trainingPeriod = 5
forecastPeriod = 5
for (i in startYear:endYear)
{
  result = forecast('^GSPC', '^RUT', paste(i-trainingPeriod-forecastPeriod, '-01-01', sep=""), paste(i-forecastPeriod, '-01-01', sep=""), paste(i, '-01-01', sep=""))
  print(result)
  result = forecast('^GSPC', '^RUT', paste(i-trainingPeriod-forecastPeriod, '-04-01', sep=""), paste(i-forecastPeriod, '-04-01', sep=""), paste(i, '-04-01', sep=""))
  print(result)
  result = forecast('^GSPC', '^RUT', paste(i-trainingPeriod-forecastPeriod, '-07-01', sep=""), paste(i-forecastPeriod, '-07-01', sep=""), paste(i, '-07-01', sep=""))
  print(result)
  result = forecast('^GSPC', '^RUT', paste(i-trainingPeriod-forecastPeriod, '-10-01', sep=""), paste(i-forecastPeriod, '-10-01', sep=""), paste(i, '-10-01', sep=""))
  print(result)
  print("====================================================================================")
}

sink()
sink(type="message")
```

Does anyone know what could be going wrong? I realize that DCC becomes increasingly inaccurate for longer forecasting ranges, but I'm not sure if this is causing the problem. Thanks so much for any advice.

Comment: Curious about your question, were you able to perform the forecast? Working on the same problem here.